# UIScrollView continues to delay Content touches event seting delaysContentTouches to NO

Tags: ios, ios6, uiscrollview, uitouch

I'm creating a scrollview, inside it I have dragables views. The problem is that the touchBegan: method of the views inside the scrollView calls are delayed and they don't arrive if the move is done quickly, can anyone say me why? Here is some of my code:

```
    //At the init method of my UIScrollView subclass
    self.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
    self.delaysContentTouches = NO;
    self.delegate = self;


    //At the init of the view in the content
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
    self.exclusiveTouch = YES;
```

I have tried to remove the UIScrollView of the hierarchy and replace it for a current view that don't do scroll and all works fine so i'm sure is the UIScrollView who provokes the delay.

Also say i'm programming on iOS 6 framework